# div line-spans with ::after content affects cursor in empty lines

Tags: html, css

In this example: https://tueksta.github.io/adblock-filter-analyzer/index.html you can see a div with multiline text, where I managed to make spaces and linebreaks visible, but not affect mouse or selection.

```css
#rich-text {
  position: relative;
}

.space {
pointer-events: none;
  display: inline-block;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, currentColor, rgba(0,0,0,0) 2px);
}

#rich-text .line .error::after {
  content: "⛔";
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  right: 8px;
}

.line:after {
  pointer-events: none;
  color: rgba(127,127,127,.33);
  content: "¬";
}
```

```html
    <div id="rich-text" contenteditable="true">
        <span class="line">
          <span class="domain error" data-error-message="no spaces allowed in domains">bad<span class="space"> </span>filter</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <br>
      </div>
```

For spaces I used `background` in CSS and it works fine. For linebreaks I wrapped the whole line in a `<span>` and added some `::after` style with `content:` property. It also works for, except for the case when the line is empty. So if I have

```
<span class="line"></span><br>
```

the `¬` shows up nicely, but when I click on that line, the cursor is put behind the `¬` and not before.

I fiddled around and managed to get right cursor position by adding some invisible html entity to the `<span>` like `&zwj;`. But then I introduce a new weird behavior where keyboard navigation has an extra step.

I don't want to go to extremes like customizing the keyboard navigation with javascript, or putting the linebreak icon into a background icon. Is there any other solution possible with plain html/css?

Comment: For anybody who doesn't feel like clicking the link, this is not about a `<textarea>`, it's about a `<div>` with "contenteditable" set.

Comment: Please put just enough code into your question, preferably as a runnable snippet, to demonstrate the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It seems to be the <br> element, try deleting that and use display: block; for .line.

Comment: @prkos thanks, great idea, and it works like a charm. I also needed to remove the `display: inline-block;` from space-spans, so that keyboard navigation works, but now it's good! Wanna add an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pseudo-elements is a great idea is a great idea in this case where you don't want them to be selectable with the rest of the text.

It isn't the pseudo-elements that make the empty lines mouse pointer seemingly "see" the pseudo-element character, it is the `<br>` element after the line that is introducing spaces and pointer events.

If I remove the `<br>`s in your linked example and set the `.line` to be a block-level elements to make up for the deletion of 
s I get the desired behavior.

Alternatively, you could remove pointer events from the `<br>`.

I prefer cleaner HTML, if it works for all your other purposes, here it is without the breaks and with the adjustment you mentioned in the comment for the space-spans:

```css
#rich-text {
  position: relative;
}

.space {
  pointer-events: none;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, currentColor, rgba(0,0,0,0) 2px);
}

#rich-text .line .error::after {
  content: "⛔";
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  right: 8px;
}

.line {
  display: block;
}

.line:after {
  pointer-events: none;
  color: rgba(127,127,127,.33);
  content: "¬";
}
```

```html
    <div id="rich-text" contenteditable="true">
        <span class="line">
          <span class="domain error" data-error-message="no spaces allowed in domains">bad<span class="space"> </span>filter</span>
        </span>
        <span class="line"></span>
      </div>
```